# Android Studio not installing app on device, no error messages

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a clean Android project on Android Studio (just with a "hello world' screen), and I'm trying to install the app on my Samsung Galaxy S10e.

I click the Run button, and this is what I see in the **Build Output**:
[image: build-output]

**And the apk is generated successfully.**
But it's not launched and not installed on the device (no icon, and it doesn't appear in the apps list).

When I try manually installing the apk by `adb install app-debug.apk`, it works. The app shortcut appears on the device, it's added to the apps list, and I can launch the app.

At first also `adb install` didn't work, giving out the error `INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY`, but I solved that by adding `android.injected.testOnly=false` to `gradle.properties`.

I tried changing Gradle version to 6.0.1 (looks like this is the latest at the moment), and it didn't help.

I also have my device selected at the top:

[image: device-selected]

How can I make Android Studio install and launch the app on my device?

Android Studio version: 3.5.3

---

**Edit:**
I'm seeing the same behavior on an Emulator. I opened AVD from Android Studio and chose Pixel 3A. The emulator opens up, I run the app, nothing happens on the emulator (and I see the same **Build Output** messages).

Comment: Just try invalidate cache n restart android studio once n next   do project rebuild n try installing the app again

Comment: Didn't work....

Comment: For me, the only solution is restart Android Studio.... Awful.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't enough information to find the cause of this issue.
But since it works with adb, it means you run adb command. There could be only one instance of adb daemon running. So if it's involved externally my guess is Android Studio won't have access to it.
Possibly try `adb kill-server` and running again from Android Studio and see if that helps.

Comment: After restarting ADB server, it is working fine again. Thanks. I restarted it via 'troubleshoot device connection' from running devices dropdown and followed steps until 'Restart ADB server'.

Comment: Restarting the ADB helped me
`adb kill-server` then 
 `adb start-server`

Answer (score 2):

The same happens to me. It is probably a bug in Android Studio. At the second compilation the app installs correctly. It is tedious.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, which I solved by checking the running devices. The connected phone had 2 accounts (might be personal & work) which was listed on the list of devices, so I had to select the second [option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdlAg.png), and it ran successfully on my phone. see the attached image.

Comment: It's good to add an image but make sure it's readable

Answer (score -3):

One thing it might be:
Enable usb debugging

- Settings
- System
- Developer options
- Turn the setting on for usb debugging

If it does not appear go to settings about phone. Then click on build number like 7-10 times and it will enable you to have the developer options appear.

Comment: But I said that `adb install` works so that means that I have usb debugging enabled...